# Conditionally ordering tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Consider a Gradle plugin that adds three tasks to a project - a `buildZip` task to create a distributable zip of the project, a `publishZip` task to publish that zip to a shared repository, and a `cleanZip` task to clean up any local version of the zip. For local development, `cleanZip buildZip` will be used frequently, but the automated build system will be running `buildZip publishZip cleanZip`.

One of the projects in which this plugin is being used wants to run their build using Gradle's `parallel` flag to allow the different parts of the project to be built in parallel. Unfortunately, this runs into a problem with the zip tasks - `buildZip` depends on the project actually building, but `cleanZip` doesn't have any dependencies so it can run right away, leading to the automated build system not being able to clean up.

Declaring any dependencies between these tasks isn't a good idea because they should be able to be run separately. Also, I can't specify `mustRunAfter` (at least between `buildZip` and `cleanZip`) because sometimes clean should be first and sometimes build should be first.

How can I tell Gradle what order to run these tasks in, in a way that will be honored by `--parallel` and isn't hardcoded to have a particular one always run before the other?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is: detect if gradle is run with `--parallel` and based on this configure dependencies between tasks appropriately. It can be done in the following way:

```
println project.gradle.startParameter.parallelProjectExecutionEnabled
```